# Отправка файлов через FormData

Tags: javascript, python, ajax

Не получается отправить файл на сервер, используя ajax, объект FormData. Функция ajax в javascript вызывает ошибку 404. Ругается на строку request.send(data).

**html**

```
<label for="new-homework" class="add">Прикрепить</label>
<button class="send">Отправить</button>
<input type="file" style="visibility:hidden;" multiple id="new-homework" value="Выберите файлы">
```

**javascript**

```
function ajax(type, url, data, callback) { 
    var f = callback || function (data) {};
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.onreadystatecheng = function () {
        if(request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200){
            console.log('успех');
        }
    }
    request.open(type, url);
    if(type == 'POST')
        request.setRequestHeader('Content-type','application/json; charset=utf-8');
    console.log(data);
    request.send(data);
}

var nf_button = document.getElementById("new-homework");
nf_button.addEventListener("change", function() {
    console.log('работает');
    var files = nf_button.files;
    canSendFiles(files);
}, false);

function canSendFiles(files) {
    document.querySelector('button.send').onclick = function () {
        var form = new FormData();
        form.append('homework', files);
        console.log(form.getAll('homework'));
        ajax('POST', '/upload_file', form, function () {
            console.log('запрос отправлен');    
        });
    }
}
```

**python**

```
UPLOAD_FOLDER = "C:\chess_school\pa\saved"
ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS = set(['txt', 'pdf', 'png', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif',
                          'TXT', 'PDF', 'PNG', 'JPG', 'JPEG', 'GIF']
                         )


@app.route('/upload_file', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_file():
    """
    АПИ для загрузки файлов на сервер

    :return:

    """
    if request.method == 'POST':
        file = request.files['file']
        print(file)
        if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
            filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
            path = app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER']
            if not os.path.exists(path):
                os.makedirs(path)
            file.save(os.path.join(path, filename))
            return redirect(url_for('uploaded_file',
                                    filename=filename))
    return '''
    <!doctype html>
    <title>Upload new File</title>
    <h1>Upload new File</h1>
    <form action="" method=post enctype=multipart/form-data>
      <p><input type=file name=file>
         <input type=submit value=Upload>
    </form>
    '''


@app.route('/uploads/<filename>')
def uploaded_file(filename):
    return send_from_directory(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'],
                               filename)
```

В чем проблема, как исправить?

**EDIT1**

Добавление формы в html и использование FormData(form) не меняет ситуацию.

Comment: Про ошибку 400 что-то было уже... как защита от какого-то вида атак... Найдите ошибку в логах и покажите её детали. Или... попробуйте сделать тестовую форму и повторить пост через форму.

Comment: 404 возвращает при отправке файла или при редиректе после сохранения файла? not found обычно бывает из-за ошибки роутов